# Velocity evaluate expression to Boolean

Tags: templates, boolean, eval, velocity

Is there a way to simplify this assignmet in Velocity?

```
#if($errors.contains("Field required.")
    #set($requiredFieldErrors = true)
#else
    #set($requiredFieldErrors = false)
#end
```

So I need the $requiredFieldErrors as boolean so I can use the value later on in a if-else statement. A definition in one line would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify this to:

```
#set($reqField = $errors.contains("Field Required.")
```

Or directly test it in the if statement (assuming you're not using the $reqField reference in other places).

Edit:

```
#set($reqField = $errors && $errors.contains("Field Required.")
```

The above line will check to make sure $errors is a valid reference and contains the required value.

Comment: That is the problem, I use the $reqField as macro param. Your statement will not work, if $errors is null. How to handle that?
`#set($reqField = $errors && $errors.contains("Field Required.")` will not work.

Comment: I modified my answer based on this question.  I just checked that in Velocity 1.7 and received the proper value.